# Envíar correos en laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, email

Quiero enviar un correo a usuarios que realizan un pago...Entonces el correo destinatario cambia.

Lo trate de asignar en una variable, pero no me permite enviar el correo.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
$data = $request->cli_correo;

Mail::send('emails.infopago', $request->all(), function($msj){
$msj->subject('Correo de contacto');
$msj->to($data);
```

y este el error que arroja:

> ErrorException in PagoController.php line 45:
>   Undefined variable: data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro del la función anónima no conoce la variable `$data`, para poder utilizarla(heredar), en PHP se le dice a la función que use el valor de esa variable de la siguiente manera

```
$data = $request->cli_correo;

Mail::send('emails.infopago', $request->all(), function($msj) use ($data){
$msj->subject('Correo de contacto');
$msj->to($data);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!, me funciono perfectamente.